# jQuery: How to change the position of a div, inside of another div then create a glide effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div, and using css to make it in the shape of a red box, with the ID of #box. Just to make it look neat I put #box inside of another div. I would like to know how can I change the position of the #box to somewhere else on screen (lets say top left), then have it glide to the bottom right of the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*Limits for Glide*/
var top_limit = "10px";
var left_limit = "10px";
var right_limit = "600px";
var bottom_limit = "600px";

/*Glide*/
$('#glide').click(function(){
    $('#box').css("left",left_limit).css("top",top_limit);
    $('#box').animate({"left": right_limit, "top": bottom_limit},2000);
});

});
```

As for my divs I have multiple things on my html file but the main ones are these.

```
.subDiv {
    width: 600px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #876D52;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
#box{
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FF9933;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are talking specifically "on screen" and not necessarily about the DOM positioning, you can use `position: absolute` and then set `left: 0` - this will position the "div" in question to the far left of the screen.  Then you animate its `left` property to make it have a "glide" effect..

You have to be careful though.  It's not a good practice to take items out of their parent containers "visually" but leave them the same in the DOM, simply because it gets confusing.  (oh in source code that's a child of this container but on screen it doesnt appear that way)

I hope this makes sense, let me know if any questions.

Comment: I'm slowly learning this whole coding thing but yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for animate with js you MUST add `position: absolute;` to those objects that you want to animate.so:

```
#box{
position: absolute;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
background: #FF9933;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much guys, the position absolute worked!